# How to call python function inside MS Excel spreadsheets directly?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

i have a python program (function) that i want to embed into MS Excel and want my excel to talk to that python function and show the results in the MS Excel spread itself. Is is possible? Is yes, can you suggest how i can proceed with it?

Comment: you can export the excel file with whatever function are using in python an see those changes.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've looked at doing something like this.. But there is a way to get python scripts called from within excel itself (Google will be your friend here). As for writing to the excel sheet you're probably going to want to look at one of the many python excel modules rather than pandas. Again. Google is your friend